# Custom break word

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap, word-break

I'm working on a map legend and I have some trouble when the word is too long.
I want to know if it's possible to add some property to the text so it break to the last symbol space, score, underscore, slash, and other punctuation

In other words, I want more symbols to be interpret like spaces for the "default spaces breakline".

I try using `word-wrap: break-word` or `word-break: break-all` but it's not the expected result... It is what I want only if there is no symbol so I'll probably add 1 of these to the CSS to break lines (by the way I'm not sure about the differences / wich one to use / why)

Here's an example of what I would like (and what I tried)

http://jsfiddle.net/uazk54pL/

**edit**

by the way, I didn't use JavaScript because I thought it can be with css, and I'm not really sure how to do it... but I'm not against using it if no better solution is found

```css
.tmp {
  border: black 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#wrap {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
#break {
  word-break: break-all;
}
}
```

```html
nothing
<div id="nothing" class="tmp">
  hi im/a-longword
  <br/>
  <br/>breaklineon-and_and and/
  <br/>
  <br/>ifnosymboliwantwordbreak
</div>
word-wrap: break-word;
<div id="wrap" class="tmp">
  hi im/a-longword
  <br/>
  <br/>breaklineon-and_and and/
  <br/>
  <br/>ifnosymboliwantwordbreak
</div>
word-break: break-all;
<div id="break" class="tmp">
  hi im/a-longword
  <br/>
  <br/>breaklineon-and_and and/
  <br/>
  <br/>ifnosymboliwantwordbreak
</div>
expected
<div id="expected" class="tmp">
  hi im/a-
  <br/>longword
  <br/>
  <br/>breaklineon-
  <br/>and_and and/
  <br/>
  <br/>ifnosymboli
  <br/>wantwordbr
  <br/>eak
</div>
```

Comment: You can add soft hyphenation marks on your words with `&shy;`. Does this help?

Comment: Words I'm using are imported from a database, so unfortunately I think I won't be able to add marks where needed

Comment: Actually I think the problem is how to break "ifnosymboliwantwordbreak" into words, I doubt css can achieve this.

Comment: I don't want to break it into real word, what I was thinking is break to N character as the word-break: break-all property do  (see expected box) also as I say in the last edit, I'm not against adding JavaScript :)

Comment: I don’t know of any way to tell the browser via CSS what characters it should consider as valid points to break a word. But if you have a list of characters defined yourself, then you could add the soft hyphen in those places yourself (via script), after you read the words from the database.

Comment: that's not a bad idea, but `&shy;` add a "-" when it linebreak, is there a way to remove it ? as I'll already have a symbol before the linebreak

Comment: You can use `&thinsp;` instead of `&shy;`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5038920/html-soft-hypen-shy-without-dash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally used the method tell in the question's comments. As my text is add with JavaScript, I'm just addind `&thinsp;` after special characters before add it to my page.

```
str.replace(/([-/_])/g,"$&&thinsp;")
```

Also I used the CSS `word-wrap:break-word;` to cut words too long

Answer (score 0):

I have updated css in your example. Take a look, if this is what you are trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/uazk54pL/1/

The CSS looks like this:

```
.tmp {
    border:black 1px solid;
    width:100px;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: You can see from his bottom block, what he's trying to achieve... you've not changed anything.

Comment: and I already try adding word-wrap: break-word property... (see box 2)